# Get console.log() to display custom object description

Tags: javascript

I have a custom JS object that I've made to represent a grid. Stripped down for this example it looks like this:

```
function Grid(c, r)
{   
    var layout = [];
    var contentPointer = 0;

    this.getCell = function(c, r)
    {
        //Return selected cell
    }

    this.getRow = function(r)
    {
        //Return selected row
    }

    this.getCol = function(c)
    {
                //Return selected column
    }

    for(var row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        layout[row] = [];
        for(var col = 0; col < c; col++)
            layout[row][col] = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm creating multiple instances of this here and there using `var aGrid = new Grid(10, 10);` and then manipulating them in various ways; adding/updating the contents of cells etc.

What I would like to be able to do is call `console.log(aGrid);` and be able to customise what is displayed by the console so I get, for instance, a string of all the cell values I've added or something similar.

In am used to Actionscript where we would use `trace(aGrid);` in place of `console.log(aGrid);` but in AS3 I could override the object's `toString()` method and that would update what is shown in the console output.

I have seen that I can add a `toString()` method to my Grid object in JS but the console does not seem to use it unless I specifically call `console.log(aGrid.toString());`. While this is fine, I just wondered if there is a way round this.

Does the console actually generate it's output based on some overridable method of the object being logged or does it do some crazy internal magic to get a value?

using `alert(aGrid);` seems to use `toString()` and picks up the custom value but I would rather peel my own skin off than debug a big project using `alert();` :)

Any and all comments very welcome. Thank you.

*PS - I don't know if different browsers treat* `console.log()` *differently but I am using Chrome v33.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have seen that I can add a toString() method to my Grid object in JS but the console does not seem to use it unless I specifically call console.log(aGrid.toString());. While this is fine, I just wondered if there is a way round this

No, there is no way around this. The console alone does decide how to display the passed arguments - and Chrome console lets you dynamically inspect objects instead of trying to serialize them somehow. If you want a custom output, you will need to pass it a string.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` accepts Object as argument(s), and if you put it there, you will be able to inspect it in Chrome console.

So remove `.toString()` and it will do the trick

```
console.log("aGird", aGrid );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [console.table()](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference#tabledata-columns) for this. console.table allows you to specify what properties would you like to view. For instance

```
console.table(aGrid);                            // will show all properties
console.table(aGrid, 'firstName');               // will show only firstName property
console.table(aGrid, ['firstName', 'lastName']); // will show firstName and lastName properties
```